# What does the red sign on 'decision made' for UK visa means?

Tags: visas, uk

[image]

What does the red sign on 'decision made' for UK visa means?

Comment: One could guess the decision has not been made.

Comment: Green tick clearly means "yes", so the other thing must mean...

Comment: Okay, that makes sense in general, but this checklist makes it look like it's been dispatched for return without a decision being made. That seems odd, and it seems like a reasonable question as to whether anyone else has experience with this particular configuration of checks and red dots.

Comment: I would go with incompetently designed website/database (posting as a comment because i'm not 100% sure of this).

Comment: Please clarify where you're seeing this checkbox